# Unity Hub You are offline. You need an internet connection to fetch new templates

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just downloaded the editor version 2021.3.15f1 (lts) and I can't create new project with it for 2d mobile core
I can't download new templates for it because it says that I need to be online
I tried to log out and in but nothing helps

Answer (score -1):

I solved it I just needed to restart my computer